# How to distinguish Markers on Same Location or LatLng in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using `Google Maps` to add markers on Map. My Location coordinates i.e. `LatLng` values are stored in `SQLite` Database. I can add markers to all of them. But my problem is when two markers located on exact same spot or `LatLng` only one visible to me. I can't see the other otherwise I touched them. So please help me with distinguishing markers on same location. My code is

```
    private void viewAll() {
    addTollGate();
    try{
        String allQuery="select rowid _id,* from vehiclesTable";
        Cursor c4=db.rawQuery(allQuery,null);
        if (c4.getCount()>0){
            while (c4.moveToNext()){
                strNumbers=c4.getString(c4.getColumnIndex("deviceNo"));
                strVname=c4.getString(c4.getColumnIndex("vehicleName"));
                try{
                    String strQuery="select rowid _id,* from logTable where _id=(select MAX(_id) from logTable where deviceNo='"+strNumbers+"')";
                    Cursor c5=db.rawQuery(strQuery,null);
                    if (c5.getCount()>0){
                        while (c5.moveToNext()) {
                            String allLatLng = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex("log"));
                            final String allDate = c5.getString(c5.getColumnIndex("date"));
                            String[] strArray1 = allLatLng.split(",");
                            double lat = Double.parseDouble(strArray1[0]);
                            double lng = Double.parseDouble(strArray1[1]);
                            String strTime = strArray1[2];

                            Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                            String dateToday = sdf.format(date);

                            Date oneHrBefore=new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-3600*1000);

                            String strCurrent=dateToday+" "+strTime+":00";
                            SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy kk:mm:ss");
                            Date lastKnown=new Date();
                            try {
                                lastKnown=format.parse(strCurrent);
                            }catch (ParseException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            if (dateToday.equals(allDate)) {
                                if (lastKnown.after(oneHrBefore)&&lastKnown.before(date)){
                                    IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
                                    iconGenerator.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myBlue1));
                                    iconGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
                                    bmp = iconGenerator.makeIcon(strVname);
                                }else {
                                    IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
                                    iconGenerator.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myGreen));
                                    iconGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
                                    bmp = iconGenerator.makeIcon(strVname);
                                }
                            } else{
                                IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(this);
                                iconGenerator.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myRed));
                                iconGenerator.setTextAppearance(R.style.iconGenText);
                                bmp = iconGenerator.makeIcon(strVname);
                            }

                            BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp);
                            markers = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).icon(bitmapDescriptor).title(strVname).snippet("Known @" + strTime + "," + allDate));
                            builder.include(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                            bounds = builder.build();
                            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0));
                        }
                    }
                }catch (SQLiteException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (SQLiteException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 markers = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).icon(bitmapDescriptor).title(strVname).snippet("Known @" + strTime + "," + allDate));
```

bitmapDescriptor: u must create multiple bitmap and make markers in same location